# Installing m2e plugin into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, m2e

I need to install m2e plugin. I was given a link 
http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/
but it says that file is not found.

Then I tried https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/, went to the download link http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Its said there that I have to go to the Eclipse->Help->Install New Software
and in the text_field named Work with type `http://Update site location` 
and press Enter

After I did it, I've got message

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException
Unable to read repository at http:/content.xml
Unable to read repository at http:/content.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the main software site for your release of Eclipse.

For example for Eclipse Luna this is `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna`, the site should already be in the 'Work with' list.

Search for 'maven' or 'm2e'