# Installing m2e 1.8 into oxygen eclipse

Tags: eclipse, installation, repository, m2eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I am trying to install Oomph 1.8 into an existing eclipse install (oxygen) under Linux (CentOS 7). When I installed Oomph 1.8, I get an error due to missing dependency on m2e. I am trying to resolve this by installing a compatible version of m2e, also 1.8. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823004/installing-m2e-plugin-into-eclipse) that I need to use the ¨main software site¨. I added oxygen - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/ - install site and tried to use ¨Help->Install New Software¨ as described in the same post, but when I do, I keep getting error that the repository cannot be read:

Connection to http:/download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/p2.index failed on URI does not specify a valid host name: http:/download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/p2.index. Retry attempt 0 started

> org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a
> valid host name: http:/download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/p2.index
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.determineTarget(CloseableHttpClient.java:94)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1084)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.access$0(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1075)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1071)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:74)
> at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)

Unable to read repository at https://archive.eclipse.org/content.xml.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert:
> handshake_failure     at
> sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)  at
> sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)  at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2011)     at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1113)    at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
> at
> org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:553)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.SNIAwareHttpClient$1.connectSocket(SNIAwareHttpClient.java:64)
> at
> org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:412)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:263)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
> at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
>
> eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170612-0950 java.version=1.8.0_45
> java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=linux,
> ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
> org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product Command-line arguments:  -os linux
> -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product

I have now tried so many different variants of configuring the equinox updater that I cannot describe them all here. Whatever I do I always seem to hit a brick wall and getting the same kind of error that the repository is not recognized. The only URL that seems to work is the update site at https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7, but it does not have m2e. What should I do?

Comment: Eclipse 2021-03 still supported RHEL7, perhaps you can upgrade and retry this on something a little closer to the supported release? https://www.eclipse.org/projects/project-plan.php?planurl=http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/plans/eclipse_project_plan_4_19.xml#target_environments

Comment: Unfortunately, this is our enterprise install of eclipse, and it is the one I want to be able to customize using Oomph. I already installed the latest eclipse in my home directory and when I do, Oomph installs like a charm, but not so for our oxygen install. I noticed that the technology packages for the old versions of m2e are in the archive.eclipse.org instead of download.eclipse.org and have the content.xml compressed as an .xz archive file. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Maybe it's your pretty old Java 8 of update 45 which fails because HTTP is here redirected to HTTPS with longer key lengths nowadays.